# Getting list of Sharepoint Site Collections - OnPrem 2016. Console.log is empty

Tags: sharepoint-2013, console.log

I'm tyring to get a list of all the site collections that users have permissions to access.  My plan is to display these on the home page, to make it easy for them to navigate to each of their sites.  I've tried the following code, but nothing form my API call is writing the the console.  It's just blank.  What am I missing with writing to the console? Is the name siteURL wrong?

'''

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

    success: function (data) {
        var results = data.d.results;
        var itemhtml = "";

            $.each(results, function (index, dataRec) {
            console.log(siteUrl);
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        (data);
    }
})
```

'''

Comment: Hi Suan, Did the code snippet in the post below work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet to get all site collection and print using Console.log:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
            //print sites info
        searchSites(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
          function(query){
              var resultsCount = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
              for(var i = 0; i < resultsCount;i++) {
                  var row = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i];
                  var siteUrl = row.Cells.results[6].Value;
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(siteUrl));
              }   
          },
          function(error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          }
        );
});


function searchSites(webUrl,success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.query);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}


</script>
```

[image]

Reference:

[What is the REST endpoint URL to get list of site collections?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-list-of-site-collections)